# Typescript - optional parameter validation not sufficient to determine type when passing it as a parameter to another function?

Tags: typescript

This might seem like an odd question at first, but I'll try to explain it the best I can.

Let's take a look at this following (and non-realistic) example:

```
const foo = (x: number) => {
    return x * x;
}

const isXUndefined = (x?: number) => x === undefined;

const boo = (x?: number) => {
    if (isXUndefined(x)) {
        return 0;
    }

    return foo(x);
}
```

As expected, this code fails compiling since `x` can be both `number` and `undefined`.
What I struggle to see here - is why invoking `isXUndefined` isn't enough for the type inferrer to assure that `x` is an actual number?

A working example on the other hand would be:

```
const foo = (x: number) => {
    return x * x;
}

const isXUndefined = (x?: number) => x === undefined;

const boo = (x?: number) => {
    if (x === undefined) {
        return 0;
    }

    return foo(x);
}
```

Why is this validation only working when making it "on the surface" but not from within another function?

Here's a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=23&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MAUAPAXDMBXAWwCMBTAJwEoUA+GAbwCgZmYySo8ywYMYAqHgG4GAXwYNQkWAEsIADQCqYACYk40sCWUp0GAPw58xclWS1eAQmSo8KtRq3CJ4aDCKIAjDswHchUpQ09Ews0nDosop26prKmBRUjCzJrOyc3AAMwsliIcxsHFzwiPHCuZKu7iAATN76hv4mQUmh4Zgo1jC2qjFaiXkpBekwWQO5yUNFCCClouJAA) with both examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this by doing the following

```
const foo = (x: number) => {
    console.log("foo")
    return x * x;
}

const isXUndefined = (x?: number) => x === undefined;

const boo = (x?: number) => {
    if (isXUndefined(x)) {
        return 0;
    }

    return foo(x!);
}
```

By adding the `!`, you're telling the compiler that `x` won't be null or undefined here, and it won't complain.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nrd7hmkp/

Comment: i don't think this should be an answer, the question is "Why compiler can't figure out X can't be undefined at the point when `foo` is called."

Answer (score 3):

Add `x is undefined` as return type for the function. See [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates)

```
const foo = (x: number) => {
    console.log("foo")
    return x * x;
}

const isXUndefined = (x?: number): x is undefined => x === undefined;

const boo = (x?: number) => {
    if (isXUndefined(x)) {
        return 0;
    }

    return foo(x);
}
```

Comment: Good answer, though not exactly my case..but it's because of the example I gave which is too general , not your answer. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a more difficult case where x is a member of an obj and the I pass obj into a validation function where I check x (and others validation if needed).
Here's my code:

```
const foo = (obj: IOBJ) => {
    return obj.x * obj.y;
}

interface IOBJ {
    x?: number;
    y: number;
}

const isObjValid = (obj: IOBJ) => obj.x !== undefined;

const boo1 = (obj: IOBJ) => {
    if (!isObjValid(obj)) {
        return 0;
    }

    return foo(obj);
}
```

and here's my [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MAUIBGArAXDASQHkAhAKQEoUA+GAbwCgZmYAnAUygFdWwYtsAOgAeMAFT8cggJ4BuBgF8GDAJZgo7VnACGwdoVJl6TFsID8+MFwC2mTfJYxplm3dbylDUJFgqIRHAA1bQAbFQATFHQBfGJyKmRaAREYAEJkVC4wcPY4NXZw+S9waBhMRABGKIwcWMME2kZHFTh0VL8A7GCw8JrsCiomxxYObl4YAAYHFk9HUZ4+BBA+ig8gA)